# creat a php login page

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, frameworks

I am a new php Developer. As I surf the web learning php, I encountered a problem.

I was going to create a secure login system for my site, with these tutorials [[1]](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL), [[2]](http://www.phpeasystep.com/workshopview.php?id=6), but suddenly, I saw [this Q&A  here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22893245/creating-a-secure-login-script-in-php-and-mysql) which recommend to use third parties framework for login system.

So, now is it really good recommendation? if so, what is the best third party framework to start creating a secure login system?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, **NEITHER OF THE ANSWERS RECOMMEND USING A THIRD PARTY FRAMEWORK**.
Please read them again.

Comment: Question challenges an assertion in another post - but no such assertion was made.

Comment: Ignore the second tutorial, it uses mysql_ functions which are deprecated. To interact with the database use PDO or mysqli. At least ensure whatever solution you end up going with uses password_hash to handle passwords. See http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly a good idea to use a secure login system developed by someone who is an expert in security, and a framework which has been around a while and is stable is certainly a good choice, rather than implementing yourself if your are a novice programmer.

Now, are you going to develop a production site? Then I would rely on a third party.
However, implementing yourself might be a good teaching exercise, if you are currently learning and not deploying a production site.

Having said that, many bigger php frameworks offer secure login functionality.

Depends what you are trying to do, if you have any experience at all, if there are folks near you who have experience in any framework, etc.

php frameworks:

- Yii
- symfony
- codeigniter
- Zend

etc.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends what you are doing.

If it is ultra-mega-security-needing page, then it isn't such a bad idea to use third party framework. As stated in the link by one of the commenter, if you use one, use trusted and known ones, such as google, facebook, etc. It all depends what you want to do exactly. For example, if you want to implement only commenting some specific topic, you can also use disqus, what almost does everything for you. There are also many login libraries, with what you can do login system.

One smart man once said (I have no idea who): There is no point to invent bicycle, if it already exist :).

Now, if there is more specific reasons, why you need to do login in (Like you want to create admin panel and other stuff like that), then making your own custom login isn't bad idea. It is definitely hard, but worth a shot. Prepare to fail plenty of times, but once you get hang of it, it will be worth it.

Do not follow one tutorial though, google around, find different tutorials, solutions and tips. Once you have gathered information, you can try to make your own version, as secure as possible, following different recommendations and such.

It all comes to, what you want to do, for what reason you need to do login system.

Answer (score 0):

[Sentry](https://github.com/cartalyst/sentry) is a framework agnostic libary to handle this in your own application.